# Using ggplot with figure functions

Tags: r, ggplot2

I'm trying to get the idea of *figure functions* I got from the [Nice R Code blog](http://nicercode.github.io/blog/2013-07-09-figure-functions/) to run with my ggplot-based plots.

Let me quickly review their idea: Basically it's just a way to increase readability and structure when plotting to a file. Instead of having to open a plotting device, generate the plot and then close the device with `dev.off()`, the suggested way is to separate the two tasks by defining one function that generates the figure and another function to write it to a file.

```
to.dev <- function(expr, dev, filename, ..., verbose=TRUE) { 
  if (verbose) {
    cat(sprintf("Creating %s\n", filename))
  }

  dev(filename, ...)
  on.exit(dev.off())
  eval.parent(substitute(expr))
} 

to.png <- function(expr, filename, ..., verbose=TRUE) {
  to.dev(expr, png, filename)
}

fig.progressive <- function(with.trend=FALSE) {
  set.seed(10)
  x <- runif(100)
  y <- rnorm(100, x)
  par(mar=c(4.1, 4.1, .5, .5))
  plot(y ~ x, las=1)
  if ( with.trend ) {
    fit <- lm(y ~ x)
    abline(fit, col="red")
    legend("topleft", c("Data", "Trend"),
           pch=c(1, NA), lty=c(NA, 1), col=c("black", "red"), bty="n")
  }
}
```

Eventually I just have to write one line to output the figure:

```
to.png(fig.progressive(TRUE), "figs/base.png", width = 6, height = 4)
```

This works like a charm and is awesome if you have to do these sorts of things for a lot of figures. However, it doesn't work with `ggplot`. When trying something like this:

```
fig.progressive.ggplot <- function(with.trend=FALSE) {
  set.seed(10)
  df.x <- runif(100)
  df.y <- rnorm(100, df.x)
  df <- data.frame(df.x, df.y)
  plot <- ggplot(data = df, aes(x = df.x, y = df.y)) + geom_point()
  if ( with.trend ) {
    plot <- plot + geom_smooth()
  }
  plot
}
```

and then writing it to a device using

```
to.png(fig.progressive(TRUE), "figs/ggplot.png", width = 6, height = 4)
```

nothing happens. The code is run, but there's no `figs/ggplot.png` file.

I have read about other users having issues with `ggplot` in environments other than the global environment and thought this might relate to my problem here. But I couldn't figure out, what the problem really is.

I'd be grateful for a solution to this problem and/or other suggestions about how to write clean, readable code when outputting several figures.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The proper way to save ggplot figures is with `ggsave` . See http://docs.ggplot2.org/current/ggsave.html .

If you do not want to use `ggsave`, just change `plot` to `print(plot)` . See http://www.cookbook-r.com/Graphs/Output_to_a_file/

i.e. :

```
fig.progressive.ggplot <- function(with.trend=FALSE) {
  set.seed(10)
  df.x <- runif(100)
  df.y <- rnorm(100, df.x)
  df <- data.frame(df.x, df.y)
  plot <- ggplot(data = df, aes(x = df.x, y = df.y)) + geom_point()
  if ( with.trend ) {
    plot <- plot + geom_smooth()
  }
  print(plot)
}
```